# Internal Storage size is less than

Tags: internal-storage

I have the Micromax Canvas A1 AQ4501 device. On various pages, as as [this one](http://tech.firstpost.com/product/mobile-phones/canvas-a1-aq4501-specification-367422.html), it's internal memory is listed as 4GB.

But, when I go to `Settings` -> `Storage`, under `Internal Storage` it says total space is 2.27 GB. The app `Hardware Info` also lists a similar amount: 2322 MB.

Where is the rest of my storage? :O

(Is it that the rest of the storage is taken up by OS etc, duh?)

Comment: See also: [Internal storage, phone storage and SD card](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33464/16575) and [Why does my phone show less storage than it's supposed to?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/83323/16575) – for a short answer, TimoS is absolutely right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shown free space is without the size of the whole Android system. Your internal storage has a total amount of 4GB (Sometimes there is less because the manufacturer defines 1GB as 1 billion bytes). And the Android System and preinstalled apps are also using space.